# searchResultsTableView not in correct position

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Im doing some tutorials about navigation bar and I want to make a navigation like facebook one. However, i got one issue with the searchBarResultTable. For some reasons, there is a white view(gap) under the navigation bar when I start the search

[image: When user starts searcing]

[image: A Gap between navigationbar and tableview]

Comment: I want to know that whether you are using UITabelViewController or Simple UIViewController ? and also you take this search bar in tableview or in view ?

Comment: hi, I used UITableViewController and UISearchDisplayController. I found out that setting the edgesForExtendedLayout to UIRectEdgeNone for iOS7 causes the issue. When i get rid of that line, it looks fine now. Do you have any idea?